# Multiplication by $x^2$ linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:P(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto P(\mathbb{R})$ defined by

$(Tp)(x) = x^2p(x)$

Verify that multiplication by $x^2$ is a linear map.

Additivity: $x^2(p+q) = x^2p+x^2q$

Homogeneity: $x^2(ap) = a(x^2p)$

Is this a correct verification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you've just written down the definition of linearity, but I expect that the problem is looking for a more thorough proof using the definition of $P(\mathbb{R})$ - so it's really asking why the two equalities you wrote are true.

Let's start with polynomials $f = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots+ a_n x^n$, and $g = b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_n x^n$ (we don't require $b_n \ne 0$ or $a_n \ne 0$). Then

\begin{align*}
x^2 (f + g) &= x^2 \Big((a_0 + b_0) + (a_1 + b_1) x + \cdots + (a_n + b_n)x^2\Big) \\
&= (a_0 + b_0) x^2 + (a_1 + b_1) x^3 + \cdots + (a_n + b_n) x^{n + 2} \\
&= \Big(a_0 x^2 + a_1x^3 + \cdots + a_n x^{n + 2}\Big) + \Big(b_0 x^2 + b_1 x^3 + \cdots+ b_n x^{n + 2}\Big) \\
&= x^2 (a_0 + \cdots + a_n x^n) + x^2 (b_0 + \cdots + b_n x^n) \\
&= x^2 f + x^2 g
\end{align*}

as desired. Now do something similar for multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: This should do the trick. Thanks. To prove that differentiation and integration are linear maps could I just use the definition of linearity--or would I have to do something more thorough, such as this?

Comment: @StVincent Yes, the proof is similar.

Comment: So for example differentiation has the property $(f+g)' = f'+g'$. Is this enough? $T(p+q) = (p+q)'= Tp+Tq = p'+q'$

Comment: @StVincent The question's point is likely for you to reason *why* $(f + g)' = f' + g'$ in the special case of polynomials, rather than cite a general fact from calculus.

Comment: I see what you're saying.

Comment: @StVincent Sure. It *is* true that you can just state that $'$ and $\int$ are linear, and that would be perfectly sufficient (but it probably doesn't do much towards the educational goal of the question).

Comment: Your answer above will definitely help with this. I'll just use something like $p = a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx_n$ for $Tp = p^{\prime}$. $T(a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx_n) = a_1+\cdots+(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}$, and then test if this property holds under addition and scalar multiplication.